# Advanced Super Ninja Search Options: hasnotice

Tags: support, search

Chossing ["hasnotice:1"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=++hasnotice%3A1&submit=search) as search option, gave back all question, where a bounty is active.
Shouldn't it be called "hasbounty" then?

Or what else is it good for?

Comment: *Insert a generic joke about what could the rapidly changing event be here.* (This of course includes the self-referential joke about the joke itself being rapidly changing.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are different types of post notices other than just bounties. We just don't have any of them used right now. Try it on meta.SO or on stackoverflow and you will see different ones: there are "current event" post notices, there are "Lock/Protect" post notices, and more.

Just for laughs, I put on a "current events" notice for your post here. Try searching on Meta with `hasnotice:1` to see it.